# UWP IOT, How to access camera on board?, not usb camera

Tags: uwp, iot

I have a problem accessing IOT camera,
I try create simple code that access camera, view live streaming from that camera.
It works on Windows-phone 10 && Windows 10.
but I got error when try it on IOT Device, it says 'No devices found'
the camera is like [here in this link](http://www.xenstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/raspberrypi-2.jpg)

> here is the code

```
private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
            var count = allVideoDevices.Count;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(count+"Video Capture Device");
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
            PreviewControl.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // This will be thrown if the user denied access to the camera in privacy settings
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed.");
        }
    }
    //protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    await CleanupCameraAsync();
    //}
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        StartPreviewAsync();
       
    }
```

any suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 IoT Edition currently supports limited number of devices which are on [Hardware Compatibility List](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/supportedinterfaces) (see [Cameras](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/supportedinterfaces#Cameras) section). Unfortunately, if you camera is not listed there, you will not be able to use it from your UWP Application. As far as I know, Raspberry Pi native camera is not supported.